# Как в FORM(форме) сделать чтобы отображались часы в реальном времени?

Tags: php, java, form

Как в FORM(форме) сделать чтобы отображались часы в реальном времени ?Учу

DEVelNEXT (php+java)

Comment: Что до сих пор получилось? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Java или все же JavaScript?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman почему именно java, можно узнать из описания develnext

Answer (score 0):

1. Для этого в DN есть встроенный функционал. Добавь компонент "текст" на форму, затем этому компоненту в поведениях добавь "Временное табло", далее можешь выбрать формат отображения времени.
2. Другой способ, используй таймер и в событии таймера задавай тексту текущее время:

```php
$this->label->text = Time::now()->toString('HH:mm:ss');
```

Подробнее про время почитать можно [здесь](https://github.com/jphp-compiler/develnext/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)

Comment: а это однократно выведет время или часы буду менять в реальном времени?

Comment: Все будет меняться в реальном времени, во втором варианте зависит от интервала таймера, который выставляется в его свойствах, по-умолчанию его интервал 1000 млсек это 1 сек.